# Why doesn't Java store the value of the conditional in a loop?

Tags: java, iteration, compiler-optimization

For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20 * 40 * 60 * 80; i++){ ... }
```

Compared to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3840000; i++){ ... }
```

The first loop runs much slower than the second (did some time-trials) even though the value of the conditional will never change at any stage throughout the iteration. Sure, with methods this would be different because that value may change (even though it probably shouldn't). I was just wondering why Java doesn't cache / temp that value.

```
long fact10 = factorial(10);
for(long n = 0; n < fact10; n++)    vs   for(long n = 0; n < factorial(10); n++)
```

Comment: cache/temp, isn't it implementation dependent? I guess the reason could be, first one is an expression.

Comment: Your second example is completely different from your first example. Your first example uses constant values, your second example uses a method invocation. As far as the compiler knows, successive calls to `factorial(10)` could return different results. There is no built in [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) mechanism in Java.

Comment: also, in regards to the first example,  did you run them in the same jvm run?  If so, did you warm everything up first?  The order in which you execute these two tests would matter, as the first one will almost certainly be slower due to jvm overhead and initialization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java cannot do the second optimization, because it does not know that `factorial` is free of side effects. As far as the first benchmark goes, I am sure this is a mistake of some sort: Java compiler calculates the results of constant expressions at compile time, so the first two loops are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I think your **micro-benchmark is flawed**, most are.

Benchmarking correctly is an art form. The Oracle JVM has a Just In Time compiler ( JIT ), I am sure if you ran this long enough you would see it eventually speed up after it decided heuristically that those values never change.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically (although I've had bad success with this), you could alter the result of your "<" statement in the loop.

For example:

```
int x = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < x * 2; i++)
{
  if(x < 10)
     x += i;
}
```

I don't know the exact reason why it does the calculation every time regardless of the values, but it always recalculates the mathematics during each iteration in case variables are present.

Answer (score 0):

I think its okay, that the condition will checked each time. So you can implement something like this:

```
        synchronized (veryBigList) {
            for (Iterator iter = veryBigList.iterator();iter.hasNext();) {
                Object o = iter.next();
                //Do something
            }
        }
```

Notice, that some List Implementations have a different performance.
I think (not sure now),

**ArrayList** is very fast on `size()`, but slow on `add()` if the
underlaying array have to be extended. **LinkedList** is slow on `size()`,
but very fast on `add()`

I prefer this solution:

```
    synchronized (veryBigList) {
        for (int i = 0, l = veryBigList.size(); i < l; i++) {
            //Do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: `LinkedList` is O(1) on `size()` actually. What you should prefer is using the iterator.

Comment: I think we're writing about different things. My example with the iterator is only to explain how can I use a for loop to. What sser dasblinkenlicht said is correct i think. My Comment about the different List implementations was only a hint, because many hardcoders doesn't know about these problems.

Answer (score 0):

What you have inside the loops since I wrote a small program and the time taken is almost same in both the cases. So it's really depends what you have inside first and second loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000000 ; i++) {
            x++;
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime1 = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("First time " + totalTime1);

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50 * 100 * 10 * 10000 ; i++) {
            j++;
        }
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime2 = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Second time " + totalTime2);


        System.out.println( "First Loop " + totalTime1 + " Second Loop " + totalTime2 );
}
```